# How to calculate distance difference between pixels in tuple over frames?

Tags: python, opencv, for-loop, tuples, distance

Good day,

In each iteration step, I have a p1 that describe the location of each person. p1 is a tuple, such that p1 = (x_point, y_point), p1 describes the location of a person in frame i goes.

Based on this article, https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/21/opencv-track-object-movement/ between line 95 to 109. I am trying to modify the lines in 95 to 109 to measure the distance difference of a person in terms of movement.

The problem can be reproduced as following code, suppose I am getting p1 as each i iteration goes (Originally p1 is the value supplied by SORT Tracking). Since I am dealing with a video with approximately 29 fps as well as multiple objects. Based on following code (inner for loop j), it might provide a false result as following image?

**EDIT: It appears to me that inner loop fails to handle multiple objects detection as sample image provided.**

Thank you for your time as well.

[image]

```
from collections import deque
from random import randint
import numpy as np

(direction_x, direction_y) = (0, 0)
direction = ""
points_list = deque(maxlen=32)

def sample_of_p1():
    return (randint(0, 100),randint(0, 100))

for i in range(100):
    p1 = sample_of_p1()
    points_list.appendleft(p1)

    for j in range(1, len(points_list)):
        if(i >= 10):
            direction_x = points_list[-10][0] - points_list[j][0]
            direction_y = points_list[-10][1] - points_list[j][1]
            if np.abs(direction_x) > 0:
                dirx = "Right" if np.sign(direction_x) == 1 else "Left"  
            if np.abs(direction_y) > 0:
                diry = "Top" if np.sign(direction_y) == 1 else "Bottom"
            if dirx != "" and diry != "":
                direction = "{} {}".format(diry, dirx)
            else:
                direction = dirx if dirx != "" else diry
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: I was gonna mention the formula for 2d distance calculation, but it seems you only need `x` and `y` separately. When you say `Based on following code, does it compute correctly?`, are you actually saying it works but you want someone to check if it's correct?  Just as a minor tip but `if np.abs(direction_x) > 0:` should be the same as `if direction_x:`.

Comment: @Peter I didn't mean so, I was gonna say that, for a single object point to be tracked over frames will work just fine. However, it doesn't give a desirable result as there are multiple points to be tracked as well as to be measure simultaneously.
These points are tracked based on SORT algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

the code seems to compute correctly but there are some optimizations you can make.
You can put the condition if i >= 10 outside of the loop for j, it is a little optimization but more elegant.

```
if i >= 10:
    for j in range(1, len(points_list)):
        //some code
else:
    continue
```

Also, you don't define dirx and diry before the conditions, so you program may throw an exception if you don't move along one axis. In the article, they are initialized at line 109.

Finally, the condition np.abs(direction_x) > 0 seems a bit loose. Usually, when you want to define a movement, you set a minimum value (20 in the article, line 113) to catch a significant movement, and not just a shiver or a negligible movement.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I agree that it is better to check at outer layer rather than inner layer. Suppose the movement is very little, I estimate about 5 to 10 pixels, since it was captured from a cctv distance.

Comment: In this case, yes, the movement is very little so it works. If you want to check N movements at the same time, I guess the best approach would be to check the distance of a new point with the N previous points, and match it with the closest one. There is a problem when the points are very close, for instance when the people cross paths, but there is not much we can do about it with this algorithm.